# Analyse and form quantiles in SQL and count the percentage of values that fall in respective quantiles

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot, aggregation

Hi I have the following data in MySQL DB

```
txnid amount type
    1    500 A
    2    600 B
    3    700 A
    4    800 C
    5    900 D
    6   1000 A
    7   1100 B
    8   1200 B
```

I want to construct four bins containing 0-25 quantile in first bin, 25-50 quantile in second bin and so on. Next I want to count the percentage of values that fall in the respective bins.

[image: Solution looks like this]

Comment: Please **delete** the image links and instead include the sample data directly in your question, as _text_.

Comment: What is all types in the output you shared?

Comment: @AnkitJindal: All types is all the including types i.e. A,B,C and D

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post pictures of text, and see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

If I am following this correctly, you can use `ntile()` and arithmetics to buid tbe buckets, then conditional aggregation to pivot:

```
select min_amount, max_amount, 
    sum(type = 'A') / total_cnt a,
    sum(type = 'B') / total_cnt b,
    sum(type = 'C') / total_cnt c,
    sum(type = 'D') / total_cnt d,
    count(*) / total_cnt all_types
from (
    select t.*, 
        min(amount) over() + (ntile(4) over(order by amount) - 1) / 4 * (max(amount) over() - min(amount) over()) min_amount,
        min(amount) over() +  ntile(4) over(order by amount)      / 4 * (max(amount) over() - min(amount) over()) max_amount,
        count(*) over() total_cnt
    from mytable t
) t
group by min_amount, max_amount
```

I put the buckets boundaries in two different columns, because this makes more sense to me - you can concatenate them if you like. Ratios are expressed as values between `0` and `1`, which you can multiply by `100` if you want percentages.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea8dde41307cdfa8687670c33280e526)**:

```
min_amount | max_amount |      a |      b |      c |      d | all_types
---------: | ---------: | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----: | --------:
  500.0000 |   675.0000 | 0.1250 | 0.1250 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 |    0.2500
  675.0000 |   850.0000 | 0.1250 | 0.0000 | 0.1250 | 0.0000 |    0.2500
  850.0000 |  1025.0000 | 0.1250 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.1250 |    0.2500
 1025.0000 |  1200.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.2500 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 |    0.2500
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot use over() in my query. I am using a visualisation app named metabase and while using over() it is giving SQL syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Need to determine firstly the intervals for each row in the result. Since there is no such values within the table. A subquery, which includes `UNION ALL` operators, might be formed. Then a dynamic query should be constructed, considering the distinct values for `type` column might be changed. So, you can use the following statement :

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 4096;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
       CONCAT('CONCAT(ROUND( 100 * SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN THEN type = ''',type,''' END)/COUNT(*), 2),"%") AS ',type )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT type FROM t) tt;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
       CONCAT(
               'SELECT "',REPLACE(intrval,' AND ','-'),'" AS "Amount Bins", ',
                          REPLACE( @sql, 'BETWEEN THEN', 
                                  CONCAT('BETWEEN ',intrval,' THEN' )),
                      ', CONCAT(ROUND( 100 * SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN ',intrval,' THEN 1 END)/COUNT(*), 2),"%") AS "All Types"',         
               ' FROM t '                    
              )
       SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '       
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM (SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS i, 
               CONCAT(@i * ((max_amount - min_amount) / 4) + min_amount,' AND ',
                     (@i + 1) * ((max_amount - min_amount) / 4) + min_amount ) AS intrval
          FROM information_schema.tables i
          JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) AS ii
          JOIN (SELECT MIN(amount) AS min_amount, MAX(amount) AS max_amount
                  FROM t ) AS t_agg  
         WHERE @i < 3) i;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The Result is

```
Amount Bins A       B       C       D       All Types
----------- ------  ------  ------  ------  ---------
500-675     12.50%  12.50%  0.00%   0.00%   25.00%
675-850     12.50%  0.00%   12.50%  0.00%   25.00%
850-1025    12.50%  0.00%   0.00%   12.50%  25.00%
1025-1200   0.00%   25.00%  0.00%   0.00%   25.00%
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ab1c21f77ea730bd394dcd0a2dff2e40)</kbd>

Comment: This won't work since we need to dynamically determine the interval and not hardcode it in the query

Comment: but there's no source(such as a table) for the interval values, or determination logic in the question @NikhilKumarSingh

Comment: We need to assign quantile values, like the first range will be 0%-25% quantile, second will be 25%-50% quantile, third will be 50%-75% quantile value and last will be 75%-100%(max) quantile value.

Comment: well, but how those interval values 500-674, 675-849 .. etc. can be determined ? How can we know those values? Are they predetermined? Is there a rule for them to stay within each quantile ? @NikhilKumarSingh

Comment: That is what our problem is about. We need to write a query to determine those values. If you look at the answer by @GMB. He finds the quantile using the minimum and maximum amount of each quantile

Comment: OK @NikhilKumarSingh , I've updated according to the logic.